# How do you find the intersection point between a ray with a $2\text{D}$ line?

Tags: geometry

If I have a ray that has a $\text{position}(x, y)$ and a $\text{direction}(z, w)$ and a line that has a $\text{start}(j, k)$ and an $\text{end}(u, v),$ how do I find the intersection between the two?

Comment: All four pairs are the same?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese no, what I meant was that the line segment is 2D and each point of it is defined by 2 coordinates

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what you meant. Once you use $x$ and $y$ in one place, you shouldn't use them in another place unless you mean precisely the same $x$ and $y$.

Comment: sorry I'll change it now

Answer (score 1):

First treat both the ray and the line segment as lines.  You'll have a system of two equations with two unknowns $x,y$.  You can determine these equations based on what you're given: first, a point on the line and a direction; second, two points on the line.

Solve these for $x$ and $y$.  You'll either get zero solutions (parallel distinct lines), one solution (non-parallel, distinct lines), or infinitely many solutions (lines are coincident).

If you have any solutions, you'll need to check to see if the *ray* and the *line segment* include that solution.  You can do this by parameterizing the solutions for the lines.  The fact that you're dealing with rays and line segments will create restrictions on those parameters.  For example, for the line $x=y$, this can be parameterized as $x=t, y=t$ for all real $t$.  To describe a ray in the first quadrant, we must restrict $t \geq 0$.  If we want it to be a line segment that starts at the origin and stops at $(1,1)$, then $0 \leq t \leq 1.$

So once you get a solution, you need to see if that solution is allowed by the restrictions on your ray and line segment.  This is done by solving for the parameters once you know the solution $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of problems are easily solved using Grassmann algebra. I thought I might show how this is done using John Browne's GrassmannAlgebra code.

Lines or rays are built up from the exterior product (wedge) of two points or a point and a direction vector. The origin is notated by the star script capital O. The intersection of two elements is given by the regressive product (vee), which is simplified with the commands CongruenceSimplify (finds the common factor) and ToPointForm. GrassmannExpandAndSimplify is a general simplification routine for Grassmann expressions. I am taking all of the poster's quantities as components of the position or direction vectors.

Defining the ray and line and finding their intersection.

[image]

[image]

To see if the intersection is on the positive part of the ray we divide the difference of the intersection and ray origin by the ray direction and see if it is positive. Of course we need to have specific values of the components to complete the test.

[image]

[image]

Just to check, let's substitute simple specific values:

[image]

[image]

Suppose the ray and line are parallel? Will we still obtain an intersection? Yes, because we are essentially working in projective space.

[image]

[image]

We can ignore the scalar factor and the intersection is just the direction of the two parallel lines, pointing to their intersection at infinity. Checking again with the specific values:

[image]